# Calculate mean by groups in R with two group variables

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

In my data 'DATA1', I am trying to calculate mean of the variable 'VAR' and want to stratify it by two other variables 'MClas' as well as 'SEX'. I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working. How do I modify it for both stratifications at once?

```
DATA1 %>%
  group_by(MClas & SEX) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    meanMT = mean(VAR, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: Try `group_by(MClas , SEX)`.

Comment: @AntoniosK It worked, thank you very much.